# Profile update birthday bug

Tags: bug

I opened the edit profile page. Filled the birthday box. Clicked on `Save and copy changes to all stack exchange communities`. Then it showed.

```
Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:

    Invalid image type
```

I haven't touched the image box.

Comment: Couldn't replicate this behavior with Chrome Version 44.0.2403.157, though I did get a year older.

Comment: Mine is Firefox 42.0

Comment: Just now updated to Firefox 43.0.1. Still the same

Comment: no repro in FF 46.0.1